# How do I send empty response in Django without templates

Tags: python, ajax, django, django-views

I have written a view which responds to ajax requests from browser. It's written like so -

```
@login_required
def no_response(request):
    params = request.has_key("params")
    if params:
        # do processing
        var = RequestContext(request, {vars})
        return render_to_response('some_template.html', var)
    else: #some error
        # I want to send an empty string so that the 
        # client-side javascript can display some error string. 
        return render_to_response("") #this throws an error without a template.
```

How do i do it?

Here's how I handle the server response on client-side -

```
    $.ajax
    ({
        type     : "GET",
        url      : url_sr,
        dataType : "html",
        cache    : false,
        success  : function(response)
        {
            if(response)
                $("#resp").html(response);
            else
                $("#resp").html("<div id='no'>No data</div>");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 104, accepted):

`render_to_response` is a shortcut specifically for rendering a template. If you don't want to do that, just return an empty `HttpResponse`:

```
 from django.http import HttpResponse
 return HttpResponse('')
```

However, in this circumstance I wouldn't do that - you're signalling to the AJAX that there was an error, so you should return an error response, possibly code 400 - which you can do by using `HttpResponseBadRequest` instead.

Answer (score 59):

I think the best code to return an empty response is `204 No Content`.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
return HttpResponse(status=204)
```

However, in your case, you should not return an empty response, since 204 means: [`The server *successfully* processed the request and is not returning any content.`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_Success).

It is better returning some `4xx` status code to better signal the error is [in the client side](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error). Yo can put any string in the body of the `4xx` response, but I highly recommend you send a `JSONResponse`:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
return JsonResponse({'error':'something bad'},status=400)
```